# How to save 100 SpatialLines objects in the list?

Tags: r, list, spatial

I need to save 100 SpatialLines objects in the list `xySpatialLines`. The below given code provides an error:

> Error in xySpatialLines[i] = spl :    invalid type/length (S4/0) in
>   vector allocation

```
library(sp)
xySpatialLines <- NULL

for(i in 1:100)
{
 x <- c(i,5,4,8)
 y <- c(1,3,4,i)
 xy <- cbind(x,y)
 xy.sp = sp::SpatialPoints(xy)
 spl <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(xy.sp), ID=i)))
 xySpatialLines[i] = spl
}
```

Comment: What happens if you change `NULL` to `list()` and `xySpatialLines[i]` to `xySpatialLines[[i]]`?

Comment: @jbaums: Error in xySpatialLines[[i]] = spl :   invalid type/length (S4/0) in vector allocation

Comment: @jbaums: how can I convert my SpatialLines object to the data frame?

Comment: My suggestion works fine for me. To clarify, did you change `xySpatialLines <- NULL` to `xySpatialLines <- list()` and change `xySpatialLines[i] = spl` to `xySpatialLines[[i]] = spl`?

Comment: @jbaums: yes, I did. Could you please post the whole your code as your answer?

Comment: @jbaums: that was "Restarting R session" issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize `xySpatialLines` not as NULL but as a list, e.g. by

```
xySpatialLines <- list()
```

or better, pre-allocate the space you need to avoid incremental growth:

```
xySpatialLines <- vector(mode = "list", length = 100)
```

and then execute the rest of your script.

Comment: I was hit by the same issue in a different context (trying to allocate S4 object output by `lsmeans` to a `list()`, but with elements not yet initialized, i.e. `NULL`). Why is this issue happening? Something incompatible between R `list`s and `S4` objects?